# How can I create multiple ranges in VBA using 'for each' loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table declared `genTable as ListObject`.

To insert and get data from each column of the table I set ranges:

```vb
Dim genTable As ListObject
Set genTable = test.ListObjects("hourly_data")
Set u1_NetLoad = genTable.ListColumns("U1 Net Load").DataBodyRange
```

The following code sets ranges however I want to learn a more dynamic method.

```vb
For Each word In genTable.HeaderRowRange
    i = 1 + i
    test.Cells(22 + i, 2).value = "Set " & Replace(CStr(word), " ", "") & _
      " = genTable.ListColumns(" & Chr(34) & word & Chr(34) & ").DataBodyRange"
Next
```

The output of this code is copied to a VBA module to set ranges.

My scripts work but I want to know if can I set ranges more easily and depending on variables.

For my case, I typed every single range. I tried a 'for each' loop.

```vb
For Each word In genTable.HeaderRowRange
    range_name = Replace(CStr(word), " ", "") & "_"
    Set range_name = genTable.ListColumns(word).DataBodyRange
Next
```

The code above does not work. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: In your **code that doesn't work**, you are setting the value of ```range_name``` using ```word```. Then you are setting the ```range_name``` but using ```word``` again rather than using ```range_name```. Also, what type of variable is ```range_name```?

Comment: Try to use `Collection` or `Dictionary` to store ranges as `range_name:range`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, maybe try: `For Each cell In genTable.HeaderRowRange:col = (cell.Column + 1) - genTable.HeaderRowRange(1, 1).Column:addr = addr & genTable.ListColumns(col).DataBodyRange.Address(0, 0) & ",":Next` -> this will populate addr with each datarange column address separated by comma. There will be extra comma on the last addr value, so remove the last comma with `addr = Left(addr, Len(addr) - 1)`,  then make the addr as array variable --> `addr = Split(addr, ",")`. (continue)

Comment: Step run to check the result : `For i = LBound(addr) To UBound(addr): Range(addr(i)).Select: Next` ---> this should select each column data body range of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question last week, I did some digging and came up with this.

Fist I define array then reDim with the the lower and upper limits of the array.
Then using the loop, populated each array entry with the sheet and range needed, noting I needed to use the sheet number, not the name, then I could populate the whole array, then proceed with the code:

```
...
Dim Nbr_Students As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Student_Sheets As Variant

Nbr_Students = Sheets("Master Lists").Range("M3").Value - 1
Counter = 15
i = 0

ReDim RngArray(0 To Nbr_Students)
Do While i <= Nbr_Students
    Set RngArray(i) = Worksheets(Counter).Range("C141:C157")
    Counter = Counter + 1
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

...

Original Post: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74899773/create-a-dynamic-array-when-the-number-of-sheets-are-variable/74916642#74916642)